# Why I get No module named 'requests' within the github actions runner?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions, python-poetry

I have a `gihub-actions` file with a part to run `pytest` via `poetry`:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ['3.10',]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install poetry
          pip install requests
          if [ -f pyproject.toml ]; then poetry install; fi
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          poetry run pytest -s
```

However, despite the fact that I've installed the dependencies via `poetry` as well as `requests` separately via `pip` still it throws the following error in `github-actions` runner:

```
Run poetry run pytest -s
  
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/runner/work/backend-holoplot/backend-holoplot/tests/conftest.py'.
tests/conftest.py:4: in <module>
    from .client import override_get_db, engine
tests/client.py:3: in <module>
    from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
../../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/production-api-4u0DyUfz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/testclient.py:1: in <module>
    from starlette.testclient import TestClient as TestClient  # noqa
../../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/production-api-4u0DyUfz-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:16: in <module>
    import requests
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Error: Process completed with exit code 4.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally solved the issue by adding `requests` via `poetry` as well instead of `pip` within the Installation depenecies section in `github-actions` as follows:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install poetry
    poetry install --no-interaction --all-extras
    poetry add requests
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```yaml
build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ['3.10',]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install poetry
          if [ -f pyproject.toml ]; then poetry install; fi
          poetry run pip install requests
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          poetry run pytest -s
```

Comment: I'll check it as well soon. But I solved the problem using `poetry add requests`!

Comment: It also worked. Thank you for your response +1

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Poetry will install things in a separate environment. So if you install something with `pip` later the `poetry run ...` environment will not see those dependencies.

You can install `requests` in `poetry`, or you could configure `poetry` to not create a virtual environment in CI

for example:

```yaml
name: 'tests'
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install poetry==1.2.2
          poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
      - name: Unit tests
        run: |
          poetry run pytest -vv
```

Will run on poetry, but you could configure to not use a virtual environment with:

```yaml
name: 'tests'
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.11"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install poetry==1.2.2
          poetry config virtualenvs.create false  # changes here
          poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi
      - name: Unit tests
        run: |
          pytest -vv
```

Comment: now I get the following error within `Install dependencies` part: `cannot import name 'Python2Supports' from 'virtualenv.create.describe' (/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/virtualenv/create/describe.py)`

Comment: Hm this is very strange.
Are you using poetry 1.2.2?
Is this happening on the `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` step?

Comment: it installs the latest version as I don't bound the version of `poetry` in the dependency installation

Comment: This is strange.
You should be able to config it with the `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvscreate
I also saw that you fixed it by `poetry add requests`. Did you not have that as a dependency in your `pyproject.toml`?